# Select values where Count(*) are greater than a number

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I am new at using SQL Server and databases - this is probably very simple.

I am trying to return a value for `JobTitle` and `Count(*)` for only those values of `Count(*)` that exceed 9. I also tried tested some subqueries but could not get it to work.

```
Use AdventureWorks2014;

Select 
    JobTitle, Count(*) as Number
From 
    HumanResources.Employee
Where 
    Number > 9
Group By 
    JobTitle;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the logic from your `WHERE` clause into the `HAVING` clause:

```
Select JobTitle, COUNT(*) AS Number
FROM HumanResources.Employee
GROUP BY JobTitle
HAVING COUNT(*) > 9
ORDER BY COUNT(*);   -- or ORDER BY Number
```

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind:  How would I include Order by Count(*) and why can't I use Having Number >9;

Comment: @Oedipus SQL Server does not aliases to be used in the `HAVING` clause.  But they can be used in `ORDER BY`.